# Solana stake split and private keys

Tags: solana

I am trying to understand how staking account split works on Solana in terms of wallets and private keys. Let's assume I want to split my staking wallet with 100 SOL into 90 SOL and 10 SOL.

Do I have to create an empty staking wallet where I ask to put 10 SOL from my primary staking wallet? In this case I need to have my private key to the main wallet and public key to the second wallet?

OR

Does protocol creates a new staking wallet where it deposits 10 SOL and returns me keys to this new wallet?

Answer (score 0):

During a normal stake split, you must provide the keypair for the new stake wallet, and the runtime will make sure there's enough SOL to fund the new account.

So in your case, you'd run:

```
$ solana-keygen new -o stake.json
$ solana split-stake <YOUR_CURRENT_STAKE_ADDRESS> stake.json 10
```

All you need is your main private key, and not the private key of your current stake address.